# Knockout pureComputed error binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this code:

```
var AddressModel = function (list) {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);

    self.list = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(list, function (item) {
        return {
            firstName: item.firstName,
            lastName: item.lastName,
            address: item.address
        };
    }));

    self.Test = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var firstname = self.selectedItem().firstName;
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new AddressModel(initialData));
```

When I run code, in the Test function I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return ViewModelToJSON }"
>   Message: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined.

But if I put `self.selectedItem()` in the Test, I get all item's attributes, but I just want the firstName.

InitialData is a simple json:

```
var initialData = [
    {
        firstName: "Jimmy",
        lastName: "Jimbo",
        address: "111 Jimmy's Street, Jimtown"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Don",
        lastName: "Mob boss",
        address: "222 Mafia Street, Jimtown"
    }
];
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you post your full javascript code?

Comment: That's all , initialData is a simple json:

var initialData = [{
    firstName: "Jimmy",
    lastName: "Jimbo",
    address: "111 Jimmy's Street, Jimtown"
}, {
    firstName: "Don",
    lastName: "Mob boss",
    address: "222 Mafia Street, Jimtown"
}];

Comment: You need  to check for `null`, since initially, `selectedItem` is `null` and has no `firstName` property.

Comment: You set your `self.selectedItem` to `null` and nowhere you set have set the value for `self.selectedItem`. So how you get all attributes by calling this `self.selectedItem()`? Are you setting value for `selectedItem` from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a computed, it runs its inner function once to get its initial value and calculate dependencies.

This means your computed value *has to be able to be evaluated correctly at the time of defining it*.

In your case, this is what happens:

```
self.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);
self.Test = ko.pureComputed(function () {
  var firstname = /* self.selectedItem() */ null.firstName;
}
```

This throws an error:

```js
var selection = null;
try {
  selection.firstName
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

You can solve it by checking if there's a selection:

```
self.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);
self.Test = ko.pureComputed(function () {
  var firstname = (self.selectedItem() || {}).firstName
}
```